# Ubuntu 22.04 on Dell Precision 3560: Boot fails with failure to start network manager and dbus message bus

Tags: boot, dbus

The Dell Precision 3560 is single-boot, running Kubuntu 22.04.

Here's a picture of what happens when I try to boot:
[image: boot failure errors]

The ACPI BIOS errors don't seem to be the cause. When I tried booting with acpi=off, I got this:
[image: boot failure errors with acpi=off]

This happens with both the wireless adapter and wired. Could the cause be dbus failing to start? I am able to boot into recovery and resume normal boot, but can't get past the user login screen of `sddm`. Upon entering my password I am brought back to the login screen.

I'd appreciate any help with troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed dbus.

- At the grub menu, I entered 'e' to edit grub before booting.
- I appended " 3" to the boot command (beginning with `linux`)*.
- Ctrl+x brought me to the text console.
- After logging in, I did `sudo systemctl start dbus.service`.
- This showed me that the *libdbus* giving the error was `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/libdbus-1.so.3`.

I had added `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib` as a shared library location using `ldconfig` – learned the hard way that this is **not a good idea**. After I removed this shared library location, I was able to boot as usual.

*Learned this from [this post](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/failed-to-start-d-bus-system-message-bus/40646/15).